# f# - simple iterate on list of pairs

Tags: list, f#, pattern-matching

I need to go through a list of pairs and check for one of the values in the pair. Say I got this list:

```
let listOfPairs = [("Joe",100);("Bo",5);("Morten",60)]
```

And I have to check whether the int value of the pair is equal to 100 or not. I'm not looking for the `List.exist` method but rather some way to check this with pattern matching, going through every pair in the list and check if the value is 100 or not.

I've obviously tried a lot thing myself but it's too bad to have any good influence in this post. Any ideas or suggestions are very appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use `List.exist` then you could write a recursive function that pattern matches to extract the value:

```
let rec listContainsHundred = function
   | (_, 100)::_ -> true
   | _::tail -> listContainsHundred tail
   | [] -> false
```

Otherwise a simple solution with `List.exists` would be:

```
List.exists (snd >> ((=) 100)) listOfPairs
```

Comment: This  pattern matching was exactly what I was looking for, thanks so much! However, could you shortly explain what "tail" does in this example? Thank you!

Comment: No problem, the `cons` operator (`::`) in a pattern matches the first element in the list and the rest of the list. Here `tail` is the rest of the list, this is passed to the function so that we recursively iterate through the list

Comment: Hmm .. I'm just unsure of how it knows when to match the first element of the list, and when to match the rest of the list? It's really hard to wrap my head around, how is "tail" not just the first element of the list? Does it really know that from what the function takes as arguments?

Comment: The wildcard (`_`) matches the first element of the list, it could have also been written as `firstListElement::restOfList`, the left hand side of the operator matches the first element and the right hand side matches the rest of the elements

Comment: Ooo! And the reason you have a wildcard after the "cons" at the first case `(_, value)::_ ` is because we don't care about the rest of the list in this case?